# Limit question help

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> If $\tan(x_n \pi) = -x_n$ and $x_0=0$, show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (n-x_n)=\frac{1}{2}$$

I am not getting any idea from where to start this. Can you give me some hint?

EDIT: $x_n$ is the nth solution of $y=\tan(x_n\pi)$ and $y=-x_n$ starting from $n=0$ where $x_n=0$

Comment: I am not getting any idea from where to start this. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: $\tan(x_n \pi) = -x_n$? Is there a typo while specifying the recurrence relationship?

Comment: No, it is correct.

Comment: @sudddddd Are sure you've not forgotten to include $x_{n+1}$?

Comment: @sudddddd do you mean $(x_0,x_1,....)$ are the roots of the given equation in increasing order?

Comment: @PrathyushPoduval Even so, what does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n$ mean? Are the roots ordered?

Comment: @Prathyush yes the roots are in increasing order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $n\geq 1$, by the intermediate value theorem, $x_n\in (n-1/2,n)$ and therefore $n-x_n\in (0,1/2)$. It turns out that $n-x_n$ is increasing (prove it!). Then $n-x_n$ is convergent to some real number $L\in (0,1/2]$. Now, if $L<1/2$ then, as $n\to+\infty$,
$$+\infty\leftarrow x_n=-\tan(x_n \pi)=\tan(-x_n \pi)=\tan((n-x_n) \pi)\rightarrow \tan(L \pi)\in\mathbb{R}^+$$
which is a contradiction. Hence we may conclude that $L=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n>1$.

First I shall show that $x_n \in (n-1,n)$

Using the Intermediate value theorem, we have that $ x_m\in (n-\frac{1}{2},n)$ for some integers $m$. Since $(\tan(x\pi)+x)'=\pi\sec^2(x\pi)+x>0$ in that interval, we have $x_m$ is the only solution in that interval. Also, there exist no solution in $(n-1,n-\frac{1}{2})$ because $\tan(x\pi)>0$ in that interval.

Thus, $x_m$ is the only solution in $(n-1,n)$, and by induction we can show that $n=m$.

Let $k=n-x_n$, note that $0<k<1$. The given equation can be written as:
$$\tan((x_n -n)\pi) = -x_n$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \tan(-k\pi)=-(n-k)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow k\pi =\arctan(n-k)$$
Thus, as $n \to\infty$, $k\pi=\arctan(n-k)\to \frac{\pi}{2}$ (Note that $k<1$).

As a result, we have $k=\frac{1}{2}$, which was to be proved